# OrderBy clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-order-by

This is a method that gets data from a view in my database.

```
public static DataTable GetUnloadingPointList(string whereClause, string connectionString)
{
    string strSql = @"SELECT * FROM view_ODW_SI_UnloadingPoints ";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause))
    {
        strSql += "where " + whereClause;
    }
```

What I am trying to do here is to add an `order by` clause by id. My export in excel is done from another method, but I need this one.

Comment: So what  exactly is your question?

Comment: Aside from anything else, it looks like you're probably putting values directly into your where clause... you *really* should be using parameterized SQL.

Comment: "What I am trying to do here is to add an order by clause by id" - really? Where? Beause I see on "order by" anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one :

```
public static DataTable GetUnloadingPointList(string whereClause, string connectionString)
            {
                string strSql = @"SELECT * FROM view_ODW_SI_UnloadingPoints where 1=1 ";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause))
                {
                    strSql += " and  " + whereClause;
                }
                 strSql += " order by id  " ;
```

Comment: You might want to put a space before the "order" as you must expect the `whereClause` not to end with a trailing space...

Comment: **[Possible SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

When you have to insert something in the *middle* of the string (*where clause* or something), I suggest using *formatting*:

```
public static DataTable GetUnloadingPointList(string whereClause, 
                                              string connectionString) {
  String strSql = String.Format(
    @"  SELECT * 
          FROM view_ODW_SI_UnloadingPoints 
           {0} 
      ORDER BY id",
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause) ? "" : "WHERE " + whereClause);

  ...

}
```

formatting is very helpful when you have to assembly a *complex* string (e.g. with *having*, *order by*, *group by* etc.). In *C# 6.0* you can use *string interpolation*:

```
   public static DataTable GetUnloadingPointList(string whereClause, 
                                                 string connectionString) {
      String strSql =
        $@"  SELECT * 
               FROM view_ODW_SI_UnloadingPoints 
             {(String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause) ? "" : "WHERE " + whereClause)} 
           ORDER BY id";
     ...
```